# Racket interface & file input/output

Tags: user-interface, interface, functional-programming, racket

I'm creating an application that displays a GUI, where there's a simple text editor and few buttons. I'd like that once the text is written in the editor and I press one of the buttons, the program calls another file where I defined an algorithm, takes the written text as input as a string (e.g. (fn1 "..text written..")), runs the algorithm and then displays me the output on the GUI. The questions are:

1. How to implement the text editor with the input of another Racket file?
2. How to implement a button such that runs me another Racket file?

I've already defined a sketch of the GUI, with the text editor and some buttons, with all the panels, I just need these implementation with the files. Which Racket function or classes should I use?

Thank you very much.